# Intellisence and syntax coloring fail in vscode remote C/C++ development

Tags: c++, c, intellisense, syntax-highlighting, vscode-remote

In my local machine, the intellisense and syntax coloring work normally. But when I use SSH to connect to the remote server, somenthing goes wrong.

First, the syntax coloring can not correctly assign the variable names with color, and all variable names are purely white. Besides, functions and classes in the included libraries are also unexpectedly assigned with white color and I can not use "CMD+Click" to see their definitions, as shown in the following image.

Second, the intellisense seems to make some mistakes. As in the following image, the "m" variable is locally defined as a const integer variable, but intellisense thinks it to be some global variables in C/C++ libraries.

[image: Screenshot of failing in the remote]

And here is what the same code file looks like in the local. You can see that variable names are colored with blue and variable "m" is correctly identified as a local const integer variable.

[image: Screenshot of expected behavior as in the local]

I think this problem has to do with Vscode C/C++ extension, and I have checked that there is no extension conflict in the remote as remote extensions are a subset of the local's. A weird thing is that C/C++ Themes extension is not activated in the remote with a notification, "This extension is enabled in the Local Extension Host because it prefers to run there". Intellisense and syntax coloring works normally in the remote for Python, which shows that the Python extension can work normally in the remote.

I'm terribly disturbed by this issue. Any ideas will be pretty appreciated. If any further information is needed to figure out the causing factor, feel free to notify me!